# Latex calligraphical fonts

Tags: fonts

I checked the http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/calligraphicalfonts.html list and tried Calligra and Miama Nueva.

Do you of know any other similar fonts, maybe less *messy*. It's for chapter title.

Calligra :

[image]

Miama Nueva :

[image]

Comment: if you use luatex or xelatex you can use whatever free font you find online

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a few from my old font library.  Downloaded years ago, so I don't know if the sources still exist.  At the time, sources included:

[image]

The fonts:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I checked some of them and they look quite good.

Comment: @alfred I find the fonts by dieter steffman particularly nice, now located at http://www.steffmann.de/wordpress/test-2/typoasis/.  Then click "Schriften".

Comment: Very useful, I settled for Adine Kirnberg Regular. Also interesting were DS Gabriele and Arabella.